# Comparision of dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

```
var date_arr = new Array( "Jan", "Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");  
var Avl_date =  document.getElementById("Available_Date").value;
var V_date1 = Avl_date.split('-');
var date1 = new Date (V_date1[2], date_arr.indexOf(V_date1[1]),V_date1[0]);
          var myDate = new Date(); 
myDate.setHours(0,0,0);

var a='';
a=validateDate(date);
var y=document.getElementById("Available_Date");
document.FM_NewComplaint.Available_Date.value=a[1];
//alert(date2);
alert(date1);
alert(myDate);

if (a[0] != '')
{
    document.FM_NewComplaint.Available_Date.focus();
    y.style.border = '1px solid #ff6000';
    document.getElementById("Available_DateError").innerHTML='Enter Proper Date'; 
    document.getElementById("Available_DateError").style.display = "";
    return false;
}


else if(date1<=myDate)
{
    alert("Hi");
    document.FM_NewComplaint.Available_Date.focus();
    y.style.border = '1px solid #ff6000';
    document.getElementById("Available_DateError").innerHTML=getErrorMsg(60591); 
    document.getElementById("Available_DateError").style.display = "";
    return false;
}

else
{
    Available_Date.style.border = '1px solid #d3dbe3';
    document.getElementById("Available_DateError").innerHTML='';
    document.getElementById("Available_DateError").style.display = "none";  
    return true;

}
```

This function is used to validate the date where in i need to compare present date with the selected(input) date, The condition is if Selected date is less than the Present date then the error message should print.

Everything going smoothly but when the selected date and present date are similar then also its printing the error message, i.e its going through else if condition. I have tried the possibilities like <=,>=. But still its going inside the loop.What should i do if i want to compare only date which is less than the present date.

Comment: What does `alert(myDate)` and `alert(date1)` output (an example) ? And where does `date1` come from ? I suspect it is not in regular date format.

Comment: Sorry now its been updated

Answer (score 0):

```
date1.valueOf()<=myDate.valueOf()
```

Compares the primitive values of the date objects:

> "The primitive value is returned as the number of millisecond since midnight January 1, 
>   1970 UTC"

Comment: Please add a note into your answer what that code does.